# How to stop sqlite from return unicode symbol

Tags: python, sqlite

I could be mistaken but since I backtracked to python 2.7 from 3.2 I've noticed something sqlite3 is doing that I don't like...

When I use to use my cursor.fetch method it would return (1, x, x, x) from my table

but in 2.7 its returning (1, u'x' ,u'x' ,u'x')

How do I get it to stop returning that 'u' in my queries? I need to store the return values in variables and it's kind of irritating having to problem solve this.

Edit: Through a little research I've found a way...

**db.text_factory = str**

if there is a better way please inform me as I really don't even know what this method does, hate to be changing the wrong thing

Comment: You do realize that "u" is only a string prefix and part of the printed output, but not of the actual data, right?

Comment: thats what I thought, however i was frustrated when it kept showing up in anything I was printing out to screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sigh.

`(1, u'x' ,u'x' ,u'x')` is a tuple. That tuple contains four elements. One of them is an integer, the other three are unicode strings, as indicated by the `u`.

If you print the entire tuple at once, it will look like the above. But that's a silly thing to do, because presumably you actually want to do something with the contents of the tuple, not the tuple itself.

If you did `print result[1]`, you would see the output is just `x`: the `u` is not shown when you actually print it. That is the correct behaviour.

If you use the code you post, as soon as you retrieve a non-ASCII value from your datastore - someone whose name contains an accented character, for example - things will go horribly wrong.